# How to open FileDialog by setting Panel as Parent?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a panel that contains a File Section button. The Button itself should load `FileDialog()` upon click. Upon calling `FileDialog()` constructor I figured out that it asks parent either Frame or Dialog while I was passing `JPanel`. The Panel itself is called in `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` method. How to make it possible? Code is given below:

```
JPanel pnlMain;
JButton btnPath;
 pnlPath.add(btnPath);
 //Click Event
            btnPath.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("File Section Clicked..");
                java.awt.FileDialog fd = new java.awt.FileDialog();
            }
        });
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pnlMain, "Settings", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: why are you using an old AWT dialog with Swing?

Comment: Why not? I don't want SWING based FileChooser as I need to give native Look and Feel.

Comment: Look for [JFileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) (Swing version of FileDialog). There's also an official tutorial here: [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Answer (score 2):

I created a new Instance of JFrame and it worked:

```
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(new Frame(),"My Settings",FileDialog.LOAD);
```

Comment: Somehow it did not.. I don't know why